# Can you determine what the server-side userId is without a try/catch?

Tags: meteor

This sets the uid to either the userId, if available, or 0 if not. Is there a way you can determine what server context you are in that does not use try/catch? (This is for an error logging fn that is called from anywhere – methods, pubs, crons, shell, etc.)

```
uid = 0

try
  uid = Meteor.userId()
catch e
  # Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Weldon thinks the answer is no, and uses a `tryUserId` helper:

https://dweldon.silvrback.com/methods

Answer (score 2):

Since `this.userId` should only exist in contexts where it can be used, the following conditional should do the trick:

```
getUserId = function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return this.userId();
    } else if (Meteor && Meteor.userId) {
        return Meteor.userId()
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `getUserId` be vulnerable to a global variable leak?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't yet see how that would work.

Comment: If `global.userId` is defined, wouldn't `getUserId` catch that one too?

Comment: yes it would. Is that a problem? This is all running server side, so I don't see how anyone could exploit that.

Comment: Not exactly a problem, more of a remark. I may be too much on the lookout for scope leaking as soon as `this` is involved!

Comment: It does exist in other contexts, and throws the error "Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls."

Comment: what exists in other contexts? `this.userId`?

Comment: Sometimes, but not all the time.